# How to detect modifier key states in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard

Is there some global constructs that I can use whenever I need to access whether the Control, Shift, Alt buttons are down? For instance inside `MouseDown` event of a `TreeView`.

If so how?

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Use class [`Keyboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.aspx). Using [`Keyboard.IsKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown.aspx) you can check if Control, Shift, Alt is down now.

For Shift:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
{ /* Your code */ }
```

For Control:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
{ /* Your code */ }
```

For Alt:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
{ /* Your code */ }
```

Answer (score 138):

There's also:

```
// Have to get this value before opening a dialog, or user will have released the control key
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
{

}
```

Comment: Much better solution. It also allows you to check all modifiers at once. If you want to handle Ctrl+F, you won't want to handle Ctrl+Shift+F, so you could just check for `(e.Key == Key.F && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)` instead of all the other stuff...

Comment: Note that the comparisons in the examples above produces different results! As the ModifierKeys enum has the Flags attribute you can can have any combinations of values in the enum. If you want to catch ONLY the shift key being pressed, use the `Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift` statement. If you want to catch the shift key but dont care if other modifiers are pressed at the same time, use the `(Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift` or the much better HasFlag syntax `Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift)`

Comment: I could not catch the windows key modifier using this method. (CTRL worked fine.) I was trying to catch `WIN+RightArrow`.

Comment: @ANeves Interesting, `Keyboard.Modifiers` shows as `None`

Answer (score 9):

```
    private bool IsShiftKey { get; set; }

    private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        IsShiftKey = Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift ? true : false;

        if ((Key.Oem3 == e.Key || ((IsShiftKey && Key.Oem4 == e.Key) || (IsShiftKey && Key.Oem6 == e.Key) || (IsShiftKey && Key.Oem5 == e.Key)) && (validatorDefn as FormatValidatorDefinition).format == "packedascii"))
        {
           e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answers are better with commentary as well as code. Please provide some context.

Comment: great idea of adding it as an proprerty

Comment: When I used PreviewKeyDown looking for Alt + another key I had to use e.SystemKey instead of e.Key (e.Key's value was "System" in the case of using alt+another character, in my case)

Answer (score 6):

This is how I handle it (using PreviewKeyDown), let's say we are looking for Alt + R...

```
private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt)
       && e.SystemKey == Key.R)
    {
       //do whatever
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can clear up why I had to use e.SystemKey and not just e.Key, maybe due to the modifier? but this has worked flawlessly for me when searching for modifier+key.

Comment: Thanks - Keyboard.IsKeyDown is what I was looking for to scan for two keys at once. To capture Shift-Tab, e.Key == Key.Tab plus the Left and Right shift modifier enum worked for me. Unfortunately, I can not add clarity as to why you needed to use e.SystemKey.

Answer (score 5):

Partly borrowing from @Josh, and somewhat similar to @Krushik, and also referencing a question about the [Difference between KeyEventArgs.systemKey and KeyEventArgs.Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668798/difference-between-keyeventargs-systemkey-and-keyeventargs-key) (answering why Josh has to use SystemKey); wherein, with modifier keys (such as Alt), e.Key returns Key.System, and thus the 'real' key is within e.SystemKey.

A way around this, is to first fetch the 'real' key, and then do your conditional:

```
private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Fetch the real key.
    var key = e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key;

    if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
        && key == Key.Return)
    {
        // Execute your code.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the question embedded in my answer ;) I never actually looked it up, good to know!

Answer (score -1):

and as well:

if My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown then ...

My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown

My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown