# Difference between KeyEventArgs.systemKey and KeyEventArgs.Key

Tags: wpf

Whats the difference between `KeyEventArgs.systemKey` and `KeyEventArgs.Key`? Is it fine to trap key press event in WPF Usercontrol class as shown below.

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if(e.SystemKey == Key.LeftAlt || e.SystemKey == Key.LeftCtrl || e.SystemKey == Key.RightAlt)
        {
            this.Focus();
            CloseAnyOpenPopups();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the Alt key will be handled by the system using `e.SystemKey` is the only possibility to find out if Alt was pressed. The property `Key` would just return `Key.System`.

To make sure you always get the right key you could use this expression:

```
Key key = (e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);
```