# Not possible to capture Alt-[key] keyboard event in .Net WPF program?

Tags: .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I wanted to add some keyboard shortcuts to my program, just starting with an event handler to see what is required:

```
    private void MainWindowKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"key {e.Key} system {e.SystemKey} modifier {Keyboard.Modifiers} down: {e.IsDown}");
    }
```

It works fine, can capture (almost) all keydown events including Ctrl-[key]. But while the Alt key is pressed, there are no other keyboard events (besides the Alt key). I was actually hoping to use the Alt key for my keyboard shortcuts but I guess not as it seems to not be possible.

Comment: Did you try the same(to capture keys) with keyup Event hanlder?

Comment: possible solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219322/catch-alt-other-key-shortcut

Comment: You need to check the System key value of the KeyEventArgs.  That will hold the other key

Comment: I also tried keydownpreview and keyup. Something "special" about the Alt key I guess as it seems to mask out all other keys.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16669061/17034

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant posted the answer is at stackoverflow.com/a/16669061/17034